# file/directory permission centos 6.2

Tags: centos

On Centos6.2 I am trying to get mod_wsgi (with Django) running. I serve two sites from one directory, and on Centos 5.2 everything works fine. In the logs I got "access denied errors" for the second domain.

To find out were the problem is I created a test directory in the home dir of user A with permission 777, and tried to access this as user B. On Centos 5.2 I can access the test directory, in Centos 6.2 not.

My first thought was that Selinux was active, but Selinux is disabled.

[root@server sysconfig]# sestatus
SELinux status:                 disabled

Any idea?

Comment: I found out that in Centos 5.2 the /home directory has file permission 755 while Centos 6.2 has 711

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New directories in the home directory are created with permission 710. In the old Centos they were created with 711. Changing a directory to 711 does the trick.